# Bootstrap table custom width on each column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How to set the width of bootstrap table?

I tried to use `class="col-md-2"`, it does not effect the width. The table class seems to have its width equal to display width.

In my case, i have a lot of information to be displayed through the table which is will exceeded the width of the display, hence i need to have the horizontal scrollbar.

This is the last code i have tried.

```
<table class="table"> 
    <tr>
        <th class="col-md-1">Action</th>
        <th class="col-md-2">Description</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in Tablelist track by $index">
       <td>
           <div class="btn-group">
               <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" ng-click="Opensetprice(x.id,x.matcode,x.pr_qty)">$</button>
               <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" ng-click="Delete(x.doc_no,x.item_no, $index)">X</button>
           </div>
       </td>
       <td>{{x.material}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

tried to override the class `table` width with `width:auto;`, does not do any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your table parent `overflow: auto;`

Answer (score 2):

The Bootstrap's `col-xx-n` classes are not supposed to be used with `<table>` tags. These calsses are designed to be used on elements that can be re-positioned based on viewport size. But since the rows/cells inside a `<table>` cannot be made to re-position it just doesnt work.

What you must be looking for is...

1. A column width in `%`   .
2. `min-width` for some specific columns whose content should not be shrink-ed after a certain width.

Note:- A table exhibits responsive behavior inherently. You just need to make judicious use of `%width`.

Comment: mean i have to create each of column width with %?

Comment: By default the table will assign a calculated width to all the columns based on their content. After which you can override the column widths by using CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap table should adjust it's width according to it's content,you don't need to adjust width with css properties or inline style.

I can help you more if you share a screenshot what you require actually.

Comment: thanks, but @Autista_z has told me to wrap the table with `overflow: auto;` and it works. This is what i am looking for, i need to have full table with and not just the width of viewport, i can set the cell `max-width` which the cell won't take too width and set `text-overflow: ellipsis; `

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this in your **CSS**:

```
.table tr th:nth-child(2) { 
    width: 80%;  /*Custom your width*/
 }
```

*The :nth-child(n) selector matches every element that is the nth child, regardless of type, of its parent.*